# Why doesn't the Bottom Navigation Menu appear in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to add a bottom navigation menu for the application i am trying to make, I followed every step of the video and the bottom nav menu still not showing up. Can someone help me?

> Dashboard xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="Dashboard.Dashboard">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_nav" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Bottom_Nav_Menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/feedFragment"
        android:title="@string/home"
        android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/postFragment"
        android:title="@string/add"
        android:icon="@drawable/add_post"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/notificationFragment"
        android:title="@string/notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/notification_icon"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:title="@string/profile"
        android:icon="@drawable/person_icon"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Can you please add your screenshot for your output?

Answer (score 0):

never mind, I got it work somehow. Everything was working perfectly. I just needed to add a library before I use the bottom navigation bar.

> This library in your build.grandle

`implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'`

`implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'`